# Yii Advanced and inline search via alias

Tags: yii

I have several models with relations and what I am trying to do is to search the fields with the aliases I provide in DetailView. It looks like this

```php
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.BootGridView',array(
    'id'=>'operations-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'operationType.name:raw:Operation',
        'creation_date:datetime',
        'modification_date:datetime',
        'ammount_usd:raw:Ammount',
        'currency.short',
        /*

        'client_id',
        'organization_id',
        */
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.BootButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

And what I want is to be able to search through rows using the aliases for columns like `currency.short`. What is a correct approach to do that? Tried to modify the `search()` method like this..but I think I'm missing something.

```php
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('creation_date',$this->creation_date,true);
    $criteria->compare('modification_date',$this->modification_date,true);
    $criteria->compare('ammount',$this->ammount,true);
    $criteria->compare('ammount_usd',$this->ammount_usd,true);
    $criteria->compare('currency_id',$this->currency_id);
    $criteria->compare('operation_type',operationType::model()->name);
    $criteria->compare('client_id',$this->client_id);
    $criteria->compare('organization_id',$this->organization_id);
$criteria->compare('comment',$this->comment);
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a virtual field for that property. For example in your main model:

```php
private _currencyshort = null;
public function setCurrencyshort($value) {
    $this->_currencyshort = $value;
}
public function getCurrencyshort() {
    if ($this->_currencyshort === null && $this->currency != null)
    {
        $this->_currencyshort = $this->currency->short
    }
    return $this->_currencyshort;
}
public function search() {
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with = array('currency'); // add more elements to array if you want to search by more relations
    $criteria->compare('currency.short',$this->currencyshort);
    // You can also add this field to your sorting criteria
    // ... etc
}
```

Also you have to add `currencyshort` into your `rules()` method of main model to the line where it states `'on'=>'search'`, for example:

```
array('currencyshort', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
```

Then in `columns` instead of `currency.short` you can put `currencyshort` and it will work with filters, sorting and etc.

Comment: Thx for the reply, should I make virtual fields for all columns that I want to search? and where they should be placed? in their model or in the model that will search them?

Comment: Yes, you can make fields for all sorted/searched columns that are related to the model. And you should put them in the model that searches them.